# what is /root/.c9?

Tags: command-line, system-installation, software-installation

in removed c9-installer by doing

```
apt-get remove --purge c9-core-installer -y &&
apt-get autoremove
```

I got this warning

```
dpkg: warning: while removing c9-core-installer, directory '/root/.c9' not empty so not removed
```

The directory has

```
.c9/
   bin/
   tmp/
   box_tmp/
   node/
   node_modules/
   python/
   virtualenv/
```

The output of `ls -R` is too long, here is some of it:

```
./node_modules/nak/tests/search_fixtures/newdir: deep_dir.js
./node_modules/nak/tests/sorting_fixtures: æ.txt  a.txt  b.txt
n_folder  p_folder  p.txt   README.md  t.json
./node_modules/nak/tests/sorting_fixtures/n_folder: BBB.txt  www
z.txt  ZZZ.txt
./node_modules/nak/tests/sorting_fixtures/n_folder/www: a.txt
./node_modules/nak/tests/sorting_fixtures/p_folder: a.txt  b_folder
c.txt
./node_modules/nak/tests/sorting_fixtures/p_folder/b_folder: l.txt
./node_modules/nan: appveyor.yml            CHANGELOG.md     nan.h                nan_new.h
README.md c9-core-installer.node_version    include_dirs.js
nan_implementation_12_inl.h   nan_string_bytes.h  tools
c9-core-installer.version   LICENSE.md   nan_implementation_pre_12_inl.h
package.json
./node_modules/nan/tools: node_modules
./node_modules/nan/tools/node_modules: commander  glob
./node_modules/nan/tools/node_modules/commander: History.md  index.js
LICENSE  node_modules  package.json  Readme.md
./node_modules/nan/tools/node_modules/commander/node_modules:
graceful-readlink
./node_modules/nan/tools/node_modules/commander/node_modules/graceful-readlink:
index.js  LICENSE  package.json  README.md
./node_modules/nan/tools/node_modules/glob: common.js  glob.js
LICENSE  node_modules  package.json  README.md  sync.js
./node_modules/nan/tools/node_modules/glob/node_modules: inflight
inherits  minimatch  once  path-is-absolute
./node_modules/nan/tools/node_modules/glob/node_modules/inflight:
inflight.js  LICENSE  node_modules  package.json  README.md  test.js
./node_modules/nan/tools/node_modules/glob/node_modules/inflight/node_modules:
wrappy
./node_modules/nan/tools/node_modules/glob/node_modules/inflight/node_modules/wrappy:
LICENSE  package.json  README.md  test  wrappy.js
./node_modules/nan/tools/node_modules/glob/node_modules/inflight/node_modules/wrappy/test:
basic.js
./node_modules/nan/tools/node_modules/glob/node_modules/inherits:
inherits_browser.js  inherits.js  LICENSE  package.json  README.md
test.js
./node_modules/nan/tools/node_modules/glob/node_modules/minimatch:
browser.js  LICENSE  minimatch.js  node_modules  package.json
README.md
./node_modules/nan/tools/node_modules/glob/node_modules/minimatch/node_modules:
brace-expansion
./node_modules/node-gyp/node_modules/semver: bin         head.js.txt
Makefile    README.md      semver.browser.js.gz  semver.min.js     test
foot.js.txt  LICENSE      package.json  semver.browser.js  semver.js
semver.min.js.gz
./node_modules/node-gyp/node_modules/semver/bin: semver
./node_modules/node-gyp/node_modules/semver/test:
amd.js  big-numbers.js  clean.js  gtr.js  index.js  ltr.js
major-minor-patch.js  no-module.js
./node_modules/node-gyp/node_modules/tar: examples  lib
LICENCE node_modules  package.json  README.md  tar.js  test
./node_modules/node-gyp/node_modules/tar/examples: extracter.js
packer.js  reader.js
./node_modules/node-gyp/node_modules/tar/lib: buffer-entry.js
entry-writer.js     extended-header-writer.js   global-header-writer.js
pack.js entry.js     extended-header.js  extract.js         header.js
parse.js
./node_modules/node-gyp/node_modules/tar/node_modules: block-stream
inherits
./node_modules/node-gyp/node_modules/tar/node_modules/block-stream:
bench  block-stream.js  LICENCE  LICENSE  package.json  README.md  test
./node_modules/node-gyp/node_modules/tar/node_modules/block-stream/bench:
block-stream.js  block-stream-pause.js  dropper.js  dropper-pause.js
./node_modules/node-gyp/node_modules/tar/node_modules/block-stream/test:
basic.js  nopad.js  nopad-thorough.js  pause-resume.js  thorough.js
two-stream.js
./node_modules/node-gyp/node_modules/tar/node_modules/inherits:
inherits_browser.js  inherits.js  LICENSE  package.json  README.md
test.js
./node_modules/node-gyp/node_modules/tar/test: 00-setup-fixtures.js
extract.js  extract-move.js  fixtures.tgz  header.js  pack.js
pack-no-proprietary.js  parse.js  zz-cleanup.js
./node_modules/node-gyp/node_modules/which: bin  LICENSE  node_modules
package.json  README.md  test  which.js
./node_modules/node-gyp/node_modules/which/bin: which
./node_modules/node-gyp/node_modules/which/node_modules: is-absolute
isexe
./node_modules/node-gyp/node_modules/which/node_modules/is-absolute:
index.js  LICENSE  node_modules  package.json  README.md
./node_modules/node-gyp/node_modules/which/node_modules/is-absolute/node_modules:
is-relative
./node_modules/node-gyp/node_modules/which/node_modules/is-absolute/node_modules/is-relative:
index.js  LICENSE-MIT  package.json  README.md
./node_modules/node-gyp/node_modules/which/node_modules/isexe:
access.js  index.js  mode.js  package.json  README.md  test
windows.js
./node_modules/node-gyp/node_modules/which/node_modules/isexe/test:
basic.js
./node_modules/node-gyp/node_modules/which/test: basic.js  bin.js
windows.js
./node_modules/node-gyp/src: win_delay_load_hook.c
./node_modules/pty.js: binding.gyp  build  deps  index.js  lib
LICENSE  Makefile  package.json  README.md  src  wscript
./node_modules/pty.js/build: binding.Makefile  config.gypi  Makefile
pty.target.mk   Release
./node_modules/pty.js/build/Release: obj.target  pty.node
./node_modules/pty.js/build/Release/obj.target: pty  pty.node
./node_modules/pty.js/build/Release/obj.target/pty: src
./node_modules/pty.js/build/Release/obj.target/pty/src: unix
./node_modules/pty.js/build/Release/obj.target/pty/src/unix: pty.o
./node_modules/pty.js/deps: winpty
./node_modules/pty.js/deps/winpty: agent  config.mk  configure
include  libwinpty  LICENSE  Makefile  misc  Notes.txt  README.rst
shared  unix-adapter  winpty.gyp
./node_modules/pty.js/deps/winpty/agent: AgentAssert.cc Agent.h
Coord.cc     EventLoop.cc  Makefile   SmallRect.cc  Terminal.h
AgentAssert.h   ConsoleInput.cc  Coord.h      EventLoop.h   NamedPipe.cc
SmallRect.h Win32Console.cc Agent.cc    ConsoleInput.h   DsrSender.h
main.cc     NamedPipe.h   Terminal.cc   Win32Console.h
./node_modules/pty.js/deps/winpty/include: winpty.h
./node_modules/pty.js/deps/winpty/libwinpty: Makefile  winpty.cc
./node_modules/pty.js/deps/winpty/misc:
build_win32.sh  DebugServer.py  SelectAllTest.cc  ShowConsoleInput.cc
UnixEcho.cc Win32Echo1.cc  Win32Test1.cc  Win32Test3.cc
DebugClient.py  FormatChar.h    ShowArgv.cc   Spew.py
VkEscapeTest.cc Win32Echo2.cc  Win32Test2.cc  Win32Write1.cc
./node_modules/pty.js/deps/winpty/shared: AgentMsg.h  Buffer.h
c99_snprintf.h  DebugClient.cc  DebugClient.h
./node_modules/pty.js/deps/winpty/unix-adapter: main.cc  Makefile
Shared.cc
./node_modules/pty.js/lib: pty.js   pty_win.js
./node_modules/pty.js/src: unix  win
./node_modules/pty.js/src/unix: pty.cc
./node_modules/pty.js/src/win: pty.cc
./node_modules/simplefunc:
c9-core-installer.node_version  c9-core-installer.version  lib  LICENSE
package.json  README.md  test   test.js
./node_modules/simplefunc/lib: simplefunc.js
./node_modules/simplefunc/test: decode.js  encode.js  json.js
./python: bin  include  lib  local
./python/bin: activate  activate.csh    activate.fish  activate_this.py
easy_install  easy_install-2.7  pip  pip2  pip2.7  python  python2
python2.7
./python/include: python2.7
./python/lib: python2.7
./python/lib/python2.7:
_abcoll.py   copy_reg.pyc     lib-dynload          orig-prefix.txt  site-packages      sre_parse.py   UserDict.py
_abcoll.pyc  distutils        linecache.py         os.py        site.py        sre_parse.pyc  UserDict.pyc abc.py        encodings
linecache.pyc          os.pyc       site.pyc           sre.py         warnings.py
abc.pyc      fnmatch.py       locale.py            posixpath.py
sre_compile.py     stat.py        warnings.pyc codecs.py    fnmatch.pyc
locale.pyc         posixpath.pyc    sre_compile.pyc    stat.pyc
_weakrefset.py codecs.pyc   genericpath.py   no-global-site-packages.txt  re.py     sre_constants.py   types.py
_weakrefset.pyc copy_reg.py  genericpath.pyc  ntpath.py            re.pyc       sre_constants.pyc  types.pyc
./python/lib/python2.7/distutils: distutils.cfg  __init__.py
__init__.pyc
./python/lib/python2.7/site-packages: easy_install.py
easy_install.pyc  _markerlib  pip  pip-6.0.8.dist-info
pkg_resources   setuptools  setuptools-12.0.5.dist-info
./python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_markerlib:
__init__.py  __init__.pyc  markers.py  markers.pyc
./python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip: basecommand.py
cmdoptions.py    download.py     index.py      locations.py   models
req     vcs basecommand.pyc  cmdoptions.pyc  download.pyc    index.pyc
locations.pyc  operations      status_codes.py  _vendor baseparser.py
commands     exceptions.py   __init__.py   __main__.py    pep425tags.py
status_codes.pyc    wheel.py baseparser.pyc  compat      exceptions.pyc
__init__.pyc  __main__.pyc   pep425tags.pyc  utils      wheel.pyc
./python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands:
completion.py   freeze.pyc  __init__.py   install.pyc  search.py
show.pyc      unzip.py   wheel.pyc completion.pyc   help.py
__init__.pyc  list.py      search.pyc  uninstall.py   unzip.pyc  zip.py freeze.py   help.pyc    install.py    list.pyc     show.py
uninstall.pyc  wheel.py   zip.pyc
./python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/compat: dictconfig.py
dictconfig.pyc  __init__.py  __init__.pyc
./python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/models: index.py  index.pyc
__init__.py  __init__.pyc
./python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/operations: freeze.py
freeze.pyc  __init__.py  __init__.pyc
./python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req:
__init__.py   req_file.py   req_install.py   req_requirement.py   req_set.py   req_uninstall.py
__init__.pyc  req_file.pyc  req_install.pyc  req_requirement.pyc  req_set.pyc  req_uninstall.pyc
./python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/utils: appdirs.py
build.py    deprecation.py   filesystem.py   __init__.py   logging.py
outdated.py   ui.py appdirs.pyc  build.pyc  deprecation.pyc
filesystem.pyc  __init__.pyc  logging.pyc  outdated.pyc  ui.pyc
./python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/vcs: bazaar.py  bazaar.pyc
git.py  git.pyc __init__.py  __init__.pyc  mercurial.py
mercurial.pyc   subversion.py  subversion.pyc
./python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor: cachecontrol
distlib    __init__.pyc   lockfile    pkg_resources  retrying.py
re-vendor.pyc certifi       html5lib       ipaddress.py   _markerlib
progress         retrying.pyc  six.py colorama      __init__.py
ipaddress.pyc  packaging   requests      re-vendor.py  six.pyc
./python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol:
adapter.py   cache.pyc  compat.pyc  filewrapper.py   heuristics.pyc
serialize.py    wrapper.pyc adapter.pyc
caches  controller.py   filewrapper.pyc  __init__.py     serialize.pyc
cache.py     compat.py  controller.pyc  heuristics.py    __init__.pyc
wrapper.py
./python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/caches:
file_cache.py  file_cache.pyc  __init__.py  __init__.pyc
redis_cache.py  redis_cache.pyc
./python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/certifi: cacert.pem
core.py  core.pyc  __init__.py  __init__.pyc  __main__.py
__main__.pyc
./python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/colorama: ansi.py
ansitowin32.py   initialise.py   __init__.py     win32.py   winterm.py
ansi.pyc  ansitowin32.pyc  initialise.pyc  __init__.pyc  win32.pyc
winterm.pyc
./python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distlib:
_backport    database.pyc  __init__.pyc  manifest.pyc  metadata.pyc   scripts.pyc  util.pyc w64.exe compat.py    index.py      locators.py
markers.py    resources.py   t32.exe       version.py   wheel.py compat.pyc
index.pyc      locators.pyc  markers.pyc   resources.pyc  t64.exe
version.pyc wheel.pyc database.py  __init__.py   manifest.py
metadata.py   scripts.py     util.py       w32.exe
./python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distlib/_backport:
__init__.py  __init__.pyc  misc.py  misc.pyc  shutil.py  shutil.pyc  sysconfig.cfg  sysconfig.py  sysconfig.pyc  tarfile.py  tarfile.pyc
./python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/html5lib:
constants.py   html5parser.py   ihatexml.pyc  inputstream.py
sanitizer.pyc  tokenizer.pyc  treewalkers  utils.pyc constants.pyc
html5parser.pyc __init__.py   inputstream.pyc  serializer
treeadapters   trie filters        ihatexml.py  __init__.pyc
sanitizer.py     tokenizer.py   treebuilders   utils.py
./python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/html5lib/filters:
alphabeticalattributes.py   _base.py   __init__.py
inject_meta_charset.py   lint.py    optionaltags.py   sanitizer.py
whitespace.py alphabeticalattributes.pyc  _base.pyc  __init__.pyc
inject_meta_charset.pyc  lint.pyc   optionaltags.pyc  sanitizer.pyc
whitespace.pyc
./python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/html5lib/serializer:
htmlserializer.py  htmlserializer.pyc  __init__.py  __init__.pyc
./python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/html5lib/treeadapters:
__init__.py  __init__.pyc  sax.py  sax.pyc
./python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/html5lib/treebuilders:
_base.py  _base.pyc  dom.py  dom.pyc  etree_lxml.py  etree_lxml.pyc  etree.py  etree.pyc  __init__.py  __init__.pyc
./python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/html5lib/treewalkers:
_base.py   dom.py   etree.py   genshistream.py   __init__.py   lxmletree.py   pulldom.py
_base.pyc  dom.pyc  etree.pyc  genshistream.pyc  __init__.pyc  lxmletree.pyc  pulldom.pyc
./python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/html5lib/trie:
_base.py  _base.pyc  datrie.py  datrie.pyc  __init__.py  __init__.pyc  py.py  py.pyc
./python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/lockfile:
__init__.py   linklockfile.py   mkdirlockfile.py   pidlockfile.py   sqlitelockfile.py   symlinklockfile.py
__init__.pyc  linklockfile.pyc  mkdirlockfile.pyc  pidlockfile.pyc  sqlitelockfile.pyc  symlinklockfile.pyc
./python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/_markerlib:
__init__.py  __init__.pyc  markers.py  markers.pyc
./python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/packaging:
__about__.py   _compat.py   __init__.py   specifiers.py   _structures.py   version.py
__about__.pyc  _compat.pyc  __init__.pyc  specifiers.pyc  _structures.pyc  version.pyc
./python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources:
__init__.py  __init__.pyc
./python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/progress:
bar.py  bar.pyc  counter.py  counter.pyc  helpers.py  helpers.pyc
__init__.py __init__.pyc  spinner.py  spinner.pyc
./python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests: adapters.py
auth.py   certs.pyc   cookies.pyc     hooks.pyc     models.pyc
status_codes.py   utils.py adapters.pyc  auth.pyc     compat.py
exceptions.py   __init__.py   packages    status_codes.pyc  utils.pyc
api.py        cacert.pem  compat.pyc  exceptions.pyc  __init__.pyc
sessions.py   structures.py api.pyc       certs.py    cookies.py
hooks.py          models.py     sessions.pyc  structures.pyc
./python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages:
chardet  __init__.py  __init__.pyc  urllib3
./python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/chardet:
big5freq.py     codingstatemachine.pyc  euckrfreq.py      hebrewprober.pyc
langhebrewmodel.py    mbcssm.pyc
big5freq.pyc        compat.py       euckrfreq.pyc     __init__.py
langhebrewmodel.pyc   sbcharsetprober.py
big5prober.py       compat.pyc      euckrprober.py    __init__.pyc
langhungarianmodel.py   sbcharsetprober.pyc
big5prober.pyc      constants.py        euckrprober.pyc   jisfreq.py
langhungarianmodel.pyc  sbcsgroupprober.py
chardetect.py       constants.pyc       euctwfreq.py      jisfreq.pyc
langthaimodel.py      sbcsgroupprober.pyc
chardetect.pyc      cp949prober.py      euctwfreq.pyc     jpcntx.py
langthaimodel.pyc     sjisprober.py
chardistribution.py cp949prober.pyc     euctwprober.py    jpcntx.pyc
latin1prober.py   sjisprober.pyc
chardistribution.pyc    escprober.py        euctwprober.pyc
langbulgarianmodel.py   latin1prober.pyc      universaldetector.py
charsetgroupprober.py   escprober.pyc       gb2312freq.py
langbulgarianmodel.pyc  mbcharsetprober.py    universaldetector.pyc
charsetgroupprober.pyc  escsm.py        gb2312freq.pyc
langcyrillicmodel.py      mbcharsetprober.pyc     utf8prober.py
charsetprober.py    escsm.pyc       gb2312prober.py   langcyrillicmodel.pyc
mbcsgroupprober.py    utf8prober.pyc
charsetprober.pyc   eucjpprober.py      gb2312prober.pyc  langgreekmodel.py
mbcsgroupprober.pyc
codingstatemachine.py   eucjpprober.pyc     hebrewprober.py
langgreekmodel.pyc    mbcssm.py
./python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3:
_collections.py    connectionpool.pyc  contrib         fields.py    filepost.pyc  packages     request.py   response.pyc
_collections.pyc   connection.py       exceptions.py   fields.pyc   __init__.py   poolmanager.py   request.pyc  util connectionpool.py  connection.pyc      exceptions.pyc  filepost.py  __init__.pyc
poolmanager.pyc  response.py
./python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/contrib:
__init__.py  __init__.pyc  ntlmpool.py  ntlmpool.pyc  pyopenssl.py  pyopenssl.pyc
./python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/packages:
__init__.py  __init__.pyc  ordered_dict.py  ordered_dict.pyc  six.py  six.pyc  ssl_match_hostname
./python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/packages/ssl_match_hostname:
_implementation.py  _implementation.pyc  __init__.py  __init__.pyc
./python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util:
connection.py   __init__.py   request.py   response.py   retry.py
ssl_.py   timeout.py   url.py connection.pyc    __init__.pyc  request.pyc
response.pyc  retry.pyc  ssl_.pyc  timeout.pyc  url.pyc
./python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-6.0.8.dist-info:
DESCRIPTION.rst  entry_points.txt  METADATA  metadata.json  pbr.json
RECORD  top_level.txt  WHEEL
./python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources:
__init__.py  __init__.pyc  tests  _vendor
./python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/tests:
__init__.py  __init__.pyc  test_pkg_resources.py  test_pkg_resources.pyc  test_resources.py  test_resources.pyc
./python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor:
__init__.py  __init__.pyc  packaging
./python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/packaging:
__about__.py   _compat.py   __init__.py   specifiers.py   _structures.py   version.py
__about__.pyc  _compat.pyc  __init__.pyc  specifiers.pyc  _structures.pyc  version.pyc
./python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools: archive_util.py
compat.pyc   gui-64.exe    msvc9_support.pyc  py31compat.pyc
ssl_support.pyc    windows_support.py archive_util.pyc  depends.py
gui-arm-32.exe    package_index.py   sandbox.py  tests
windows_support.pyc cli-32.exe    depends.pyc    gui.exe
package_index.pyc  sandbox.pyc   unicode_utils.py cli-64.exe      dist.py
__init__.py    py26compat.py      script (dev).tmpl  unicode_utils.pyc cli-arm-32.exe     dist.pyc   __init__.pyc      py26compat.pyc
script.tmpl  utils.py cli.exe         extension.py   lib2to3_ex.py
py27compat.py      site-patch.py     utils.pyc command        extension.pyc
lib2to3_ex.pyc    py27compat.pyc     site-patch.pyc  version.py
compat.py     gui-32.exe     msvc9_support.py  py31compat.py
ssl_support.py   version.pyc
./python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command: alias.py
bdist_wininst.pyc  easy_install.py    install_egg_info.pyc  launcher
manifest.xml  sdist.py        upload_docs.pyc alias.pyc
build_ext.py         easy_install.pyc     install_lib.py    register.py
sdist.pyc bdist_egg.py    build_ext.pyc      egg_info.py
install_lib.pyc register.pyc           setopt.py bdist_egg.pyc
build_py.py      egg_info.pyc     install.py        rotate.py
setopt.pyc bdist_rpm.py   build_py.pyc       __init__.py
install.pyc     rotate.pyc         test.py bdist_rpm.pyc      develop.py
__init__.pyc      install_scripts.py    saveopts.py        test.pyc bdist_wininst.py  develop.pyc        install_egg_info.py
install_scripts.pyc saveopts.pyc           upload_docs.py
./python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/tests: contexts.py
py26compat.py         test_build_ext.py      test_egg_info.py
test_msvc9compiler.py   test_test.py contexts.pyc    py26compat.pyc
test_build_ext.pyc     test_egg_info.pyc         test_msvc9compiler.pyc
test_test.pyc environment.py     script-with-bom.py   test_develop.py
test_find_packages.py   test_packageindex.py    test_upload_docs.py
environment.pyc  script-with-bom.pyc  test_develop.pyc
test_find_packages.pyc  test_packageindex.pyc   test_upload_docs.pyc
fixtures.py  server.py        test_dist_info.py
test_integration.py     test_sandbox.py      test_windows_wrappers.py
fixtures.pyc     server.pyc       test_dist_info.pyc
test_integration.pyc    test_sandbox.pyc
test_windows_wrappers.pyc
__init__.py  test_bdist_egg.py    test_easy_install.py   test_markerlib.py       test_sdist.py       textwrap.py
__init__.pyc     test_bdist_egg.pyc   test_easy_install.pyc  test_markerlib.pyc      test_sdist.pyc      textwrap.pyc
./python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-12.0.5.dist-info:
dependency_links.txt  DESCRIPTION.rst  entry_points.txt  METADATA
metadata.json  RECORD  top_level.txt  WHEEL zip-safe
./python/local: bin  include  lib
./tmp:
./virtualenv-12.0.7: AUTHORS.txt  docs    MANIFEST.in  README.rst
setup.cfg  virtualenv.egg-info  virtualenv.py   virtualenv_support
bin      LICENSE.txt  PKG-INFO     scripts     setup.py
virtualenv_embedded  virtualenv.pyc
./virtualenv-12.0.7/bin: rebuild-script.py
./virtualenv-12.0.7/docs: changes.rst  conf.py  development.rst
index.rst  installation.rst  make.bat  Makefile reference.rst
userguide.rst
./virtualenv-12.0.7/scripts: virtualenv
./virtualenv-12.0.7/virtualenv.egg-info: dependency_links.txt
entry_points.txt    not-zip-safe  pbr.json  PKG-INFO  SOURCES.txt
top_level.txt
./virtualenv-12.0.7/virtualenv_embedded: activate.bat  activate.fish
activate.sh       deactivate.bat  distutils-init.py activate.csh
activate.ps1   activate_this.py  distutils.cfg   site.py
./virtualenv-12.0.7/virtualenv_support:
__init__.py  pip-6.0.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl  setuptools-12.0.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

so I'm wondering if I can just remove that directory wit `rm -r .c9`. These are just configuration files and won't effect my python right?

Comment: Is this on an actual system or a C9 workspace?

Comment: it's on a Beaglebone with the following OS `Linux beaglebone 4.1.22-bone-rt-r21 #1 Thu Apr 21 14:28:38 UTC 2016 armv7l GNU/Linux`

Comment: (excuse me, I don't know much about beaglebones) Did it come with c9 or did you install it yourself? If you installed it yourself I think it would be safe to remove

Comment: it came with c9 on it already but I don't need it and also it always throws an error when I do an update

Comment: Can you please update your question with a `ls -R` of that folder? Also, if you think it might hurt something, you might want to a `whereis <insert name of binary here in bin folder>` and see if it's in your PATH

Comment: ok, if I do a `whereis python` none of the outcome points to the `.c9` directory

Comment: If you are running beaglebone OS where is Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a part of a Cloud9 SDK. It seems very strange for them to install software to root in a hidden folder and even stranger that they're not able to remove it properly afterwards.

But if your goal is to remove it, you can do that by running `sudo rm -Rf /root/.c9`